# View is not found

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, prism

I have a problem with a binding of the new `UserControl` in WPF, using MVVM and Prism (the view name is `SelectDataChangeView`).

So, I have a lot of `UserControl`s which work, but when I'm trying to configure new one, I can't force the application to create & bind it to the ViewModel. The problem is, that the `ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewTypeToViewModelTypeResolver` does not find the new view, so the constructor of the view does not start and later the VM ist not registered.

In other words, the `viewType` parameter is never set to `SelectDataChangeView`, so the VM is not registered. As you can see, I've also tried to register the VM manually, but it still does not help.

[image: Custom view model type resolver code.]

At first, the `AutoWireViewModel` is set to `true`:

[image: AutoWireViewModel declaration in XAML.]

The ViewModel exists. What I can add, the new View is a copy of `SelectPackagesView`, which works perfectly. Of course the namespaces, and class names have been changed and double checked (moving the VM to the ViewModels folder did not help).

[image: Solution explorer showing the SelectDataChangeView and its view model SelectDataChangeVM within the same folder.]

When I configured the new `UserControl` as a region, then View has been created and mapped to the VM.

Comment: What's the code of `ViewModelHelper`, `SelectDataChangeVM` and `SelectDataChangeView` and the registration of the view?

Comment: `moving the VM to the ViewModels folder did not help` - that's because the folders are independent of the namespaces

Comment: @Haukinger namespace has been also changed :)

Comment: ViewModelHelper is not important here, because I'm not getting the new view as an input parameter of the getViewModelType.

Comment: Then you're navigating to the wrong name. Please add the code of the registration-for-navigation and the actual navigation.

Comment: The view is a 1:1 copy of another view, which works. Even the empty UserControl is not caught by the resolver (UserControl, not VM). I'm not registering anything, just some regions and interfaces. Also using tips from @thatguy suggestion didn't help. Now I changed the UserControl type to Window and it works without any issues (I'm not assigning the VM to the Window.DataContext - it's done automatically). That means that the names of the VM/View are correct.

Comment: You _have_ to `RegisterForNavigation` for the navigation to work, otherwise it won't locate the view. Are you sure that `SelectPackagesView` is never registered...?

Answer (score 0):

The [default convention](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/viewmodel-locator.html) for mapping view names to view model names is the suffix `ViewModel`.

> This convention assumes:
>
> - that ViewModels are in the same assembly as the view types
> - that ViewModels are in a .ViewModels child namespace
> - that views are in a .Views child namespace
> - that ViewModel names correspond with view names and end with "ViewModel."

The view name `SelectDataChangeView` will be mapped to `SelectDataChangeViewModel`. Consequently, Prism will not find the view model, since its name actually is `SelectDataChangeVM`. See the [implementation on GitHub](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/342689ba9a10e511418943438d0f5c57534ca623/src/Prism.Core/Mvvm/ViewModelLocationProvider.cs#L45):

```
static Func<Type, Type> _defaultViewTypeToViewModelTypeResolver =
    viewType =>
    {
        var viewName = viewType.FullName;
        viewName = viewName.Replace(".Views.", ".ViewModels.");
        var viewAssemblyName = viewType.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName;
        var suffix = viewName.EndsWith("View") ? "Model" : "ViewModel";
        var viewModelName = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}{1}, {2}", viewName, suffix, viewAssemblyName);
        return Type.GetType(viewModelName);
    };
```

You have two options to resolve the issue:

1. Rename your view model to fit the convention, e.g.: `SelectDataChangeViewModel`.
2. Override the default mapping behavior in your application:

   ```
   protected override void ConfigureViewModelLocator()
   {
      base.ConfigureViewModelLocator();
      ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewTypeToViewModelTypeResolver(viewType =>
      {
         var viewName = viewType.FullName;
         viewName = viewName.Replace(".Views.", ".ViewModels.");
         var viewAssemblyName = viewType.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName;

         if (viewName.EndsWith("View"))
            viewName = viewName.Substring(0, viewName.Length - 4);

         var viewModelName = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}{1}, {2}", viewName, "VM", viewAssemblyName);
         return Type.GetType(viewModelName);
      });
   }
   ```

Your custom override probably does not work for a different reason, which might also explain why your non-default naming convention supposedly works, e.g:

- It returns the wrong type.
- You explicitly register view models for the locator, see [Custom ViewModel Registrations](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/viewmodel-locator.html#custom-viewmodel-registrations).
- You resolve the view models with a custom factory, see [Control how ViewModels are Resolved](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/viewmodel-locator.html#control-how-viewmodels-are-resolved).

Comment: My custom VM has correct name - others are resolved correcltly. Also, as I wrote - when I registered the View as a region, then the VM has been correctly mapped. The only issue is, that the input 'viewType' parameter is never set to the 'SelectDataChangeView', other views are caught corretly.

Answer (score 0):

> I've also tried to register the VM manually

You do that when registering for navigation, i.e.

```
containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<SelectDataChangeView, SelectDataChangeVM>();
```

Registering with the `ViewModelLocationProvider` alone is not enough.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help